# add something to Jquery selection and format

Tags: jquery, select, format, selection

Ok, so i'm trying to create an address out of some bits of code from another spot on the page.  The code i'm trying to create the address from is this:

```
<div class="adr">
  <h3 class="name fn">Boardwalk Audi<div class="separator">|</div></h3>
  <h4 class="street street-address">5930 West Plano Pkwy</h4>
  <h4 class="city">
  <span class="locality">Plano</span>, </h4>
  <h4 class="state region">Texas</h4>
  <h4 class="zipCode postal-code">75093</h4>
</div>
```

Basically i want to select these elements with JQuery and format them into something that will output as text onto the page somewhere else in the format style below:

Boardwalk Audi
5930 West Plano Pkwy, Plano, Texas, 75093

Anyone know how i can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  http://jsfiddle.net/YJrzn/

```
$('#response').text($('.name', '.adr').text() + ' '
        + $('.street', '.adr').text() + ', ' + $('.locality', '.adr').text() 
        + ', ' + $('.state', '.adr').text() + ' ' + $('.zipCode', '.adr').text());​
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly like that!  Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to set just the ".name" into one variable and the rest to another variable?